# Interpretation of Gaussian Curvature

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

In Carmo's book (page 166), Carmo states that if $p \in S$ such that $dN_p$ is nonsingular and for an orthogonal basis $\{w_1, w_2\}$ in $T_pS$, 
$$dN_p(w_1) \times dN_p(w_2) = \det(dN_p)(w_1 \times w_2) = Kw_1 \times w_2, $$ 
where $N$ is an orientation on $S$. I don't understand why $dN_p(w_1) \times dN_p(w_2) = \det(dN_p)(w_1 \times w_2)$. I know that if $A$ is orthogonal, then $Ax \times Ay = \det(A) (x \times y)$. But is the matrix representation of $dN_p$ orthogonal? If so, how can I show that?

Comment: Your equation for $Ax\times Ay$ is certainly not right unless there are lots more assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$dN\in T_pS$ imply

$$dN_p(x_u)\times dN_p(x_v)=(ax_u+bx_v)\times(cx_u+dx_v)$$
$$=ad\,\, x_u\times x_v+bc\,\, x_v\times x_u=(ad −bc)x_u\times x_v=K(p)x_u×x_v$$